# How to play RMVB in OpenSUSE 11.2

Tags: opensuse, rmvb

Despite installing Realplayer, is there a way to enable the KCaffeine playing RMVB files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding Pacman community repo and installing libxine extras and smplayer ? (Or VLC?) SMplayer is the ultimate player on linux. (This is not an answer for KCaffeine, since I dont know a way, but I hope it'll be helpful.) You can add the community repo in Yast at software repositories. (Maybe libxine extras will enable real media in KCaffeine, but I'm not sure about this.) (IF you get asked whether you want to replace your packages with pacman or not, Accept it. Pacman repo enables multimedia playback for example.)